# grid-template-rows not creating desired rows and columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Expected output : 2 rows and multiple columns

Output I got : multiple rows and 1 column

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple grid example</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
</div>
```

Comment: grid-auto-flow: column

Comment: Did you mean 200px x 200px or auto auto? In either case, did you want two to be below one, four below three etc or are they to be horizontal, two rows, in this case starting with one and five?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `grid-auto-flow: column;` to your CSS. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow)

This will specify that your cells will flow column-wise.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<h1>Simple grid example</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

You would need to seperate the rows with a wrapper like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div >One</div>
        <div>Two</div>
        <div>Three</div>
        <div>Four</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Five</div>
        <div>Six</div>
        <div>Seven</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the question I think the OP would like to see a CSS grid implementation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).